# Date validator / formatter returns None?

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime

I need a function that takes a date string as input, and either validates that the input is formatted %m/%d%Y (MM/DD/YYYY) or reformats the given date to that format. However when I run the following, I print: "date is: None". Can anybody lend some guidance how to resolve this issue? Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
import datetime

test_date = "08/19/2020"

def date_fixer(date_string):
    '''takes a date as input and reformats if needed.'''
    format = "%m/%d/%Y"
    date_string = str(date_string)
    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, format)
        print("This is the correct date string format.")
    except ValueError:
        print("This is the incorrect date string format. It should be %m/%d/%Y")
        #convert
        date_string = parse(str(date_string)).strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
        return(date_string)

date = date_fixer(test_date)
print("date is: " + str(date))
```

Comment: The `date_fixer()` function does not return anything if the `try` is successful.  Therefore it returns `None`.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to un-indent the final `return(date_string)` line, so it would execute regardless if the `try` failed or succeeded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return was inside the `except` block, thats the reason why it was returning `None` when the date format was valid.

Can you try the following:

```
import datetime

test_date = "08/19/2020"

def date_fixer(date_string):
    '''takes a date as input and reformats if needed.'''
    format = "%m/%d/%Y"
    date_string = str(date_string)
    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, format)
        print("This is the correct date string format.")
    except ValueError:
        print("This is the incorrect date string format. It should be %m/%d/%Y")
        #convert
        date_string = parse(str(date_string)).strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    return(date_string)

date = date_fixer(test_date)
print("date is: " + str(date))
```

Comment: It’s probably clearer to say that the issue was where there wasn’t a `return`, not where it was. You can still have a return statement under the `except`.

Answer (score 0):

The fault in your code has been explained by others, however, is it important that the user be informed whether the input string in in the expected format or not? If not simply run `dateutil.parser.parse()` on the date string and return a reformatted string:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

def date_fixer(date_string, format="%m/%d/%Y"):
    '''takes a date as input and reformats in the specified format.'''
    return parse(str(date_string)).strftime(format)

>>> date_fixer("08/19/2020")
'08/19/2020'
>>> date_fixer("19/08/2020")
'08/19/2020'
>>> date_fixer("2020-08-19")
'08/19/2020'
>>> date_fixer("08/19/2020", '%Y-%m-%d')    # override default format
'2020-08-19'
```